# Accessing to a dictionary on a JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to assign a value of a dictionary copied in JSON to a variable in my code.

This is the dictionary copied on the .json:

```
"Monetarios": [{"MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK":"B1"},{"MIFID_CURR_RISK":"B2"}],
          "Monetario Dinamico": [{"MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK":"B1"},{"MIFID_CURR_RISK":"B2"}],
          "Renta Fija Corto Plazo": [{"MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK":"B1"},{"MIFID_CURR_RISK":"B2"}],
          "Garantizados de RF": [{"MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK":"B1"},{"MIFID_CURR_RISK":"B2"}],
          "Renta Fija Largo Plazo": [{"MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK":"B1"},{"MIFID_CURR_RISK":"B2"}]
```

And I am trying to show on screen for example the B1 of MIFID NO CURR RISK from "Renta Fija Corto Plazo"

I do this and it works fine:

```
carga_dict['Renta Fija Corto Plazo']
Out[56]: [{u'MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK': u'B1'}, {u'MIFID_CURR_RISK': u'B2'}]
```

But then I do this, I get an error:

```
carga_dict['Renta Fija Corto Plazo']['MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-57-46b56ce8491a>", line 1, in <module>
    carga_dict['Renta Fija Corto Plazo']['MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK']

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to understand what you want help with here. Do you want to parse the stuff in the first code block into a Python dictionary and then retrieve a value from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
carga_dict['Renta Fija Corto Plazo'][0]['MIFID_NO_CURR_RISK']
```

`carga_dict['Renta Fija Corto Plazo']` is a list of dictionary. so you have to first select the list element and find the appropriate key.

Comment: Yay! Thank you mate, i didnt realize it was a list of dicts. Thank you.